# Mysql Query Freezes vb.net GUI

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I've been searching Google all day for this. I need to make a query to an Mysql Table every 100 milliseconds to check for new messages. (Live Chat Support System).

I Tried using a timer, but this makes the app slow responding and Background workers and threads don't load the data.

I need help on this badly!

Here is part of my code which checks for new requests (Also every 100 mil. seconds)

```
    sql = "SELECT * FROM ########"
    Try
        dbcomm = New MySqlCommand(sql, dbconn)
        dbread = dbcomm.ExecuteReader()
        While dbread.Read
            If Form1.ListBox1.Items.Contains(dbread("name")) Then

            Else
                If dbread("status") = "Accepted" Then

                Else
                    Form1.ListBox1.Items.Add(dbread("name"))
                    My.Computer.Audio.PlaySystemSound(Media.SystemSounds.Exclamation)
                    Form1.NotifyIcon1.BalloonTipText = "New support request from : " & dbread("name")
                    Form1.NotifyIcon1.ShowBalloonTip(10)
                End If

            End If
            If dbread("status") = "Accepted" Then
                Form1.ListBox1.Items.Remove(dbread("name"))
            End If
        End While
        dbread.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Error in collecting data from Database. Error is :" & ex.Message)
        dbread.Close()
    End Try
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: running a SELECT * query with no WHERE clause every 100ms doesnt leave time for much else.  Is the Support Staff so Sharp that they need updates 10 times per second?  And of course, if there are things coming in anywhere near that rate, they wont be able to select anything before it scrolls down the list.

Comment: Are you sure your query can complete within 100 mil seconds every time?

Comment: I tried using "Select * FROM users WHERE status = 'Online'" but this also caused the app to run slowly. The main reason the query has to be executed every 100ms is to check for new messages. I tried upping the refresh time but still the same results.

Comment: The problem is due to the fact that you reread everything everytime. Does your table have a timestamp column that marks the time in which the message is entered in the database? If yes then you could reorganize your code to retrieve only the new messages

Comment: @Steve : See the thing is, I haven't even gotten to the part of retrieving the messages. Only the part that checks for new requests and admins that are online lags the program. So I Haven't gotten to that part yet

Comment: I now upped the refresh time to 1 second. It gives a bit better performance, but nothing to great. Is there some type of way I can run the query on a BackGround Thread or worker?

Comment: Yes, there is a way you can do this. Use a timer event, call a background worker. If the worker is busy, wait, then reexecute. Follow the above advice to shorten your search by using an index. 1 second is a really short time. 5 seconds would be better. No one is going to see an update every 1 second.

Comment: If your using background workers and loading the Data isn't working, your doing it wrong. Could you post your code you were using for the background worker?

Comment: @Levi : The 5 seconds could work for the requests. However, on the live support side, this is going to be a bit slow. The reason is our field agents will also use the app. If there is no easier means I will have to change the time

Comment: Too bad you weren't using SQL, service broker would be great for this...

Comment: Ok, well wish I could help you..

Comment: Can you tell me if you were using a delegate for background worker...

Comment: Also if you were using this code, it wouldn't work in a background worker...

Comment: @MrCoDeXeR : Here is my BackGround Worker http://pastebin.com/iZLWNg4Y

Comment: Just checked it and I was spot on, you can't control UI controls this way, they are created on a different thread...You need delegates...

Comment: @MrCoDeXeR : Can you provide me with an example perhaps?

Comment: These involve delegates you would need to implement... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24421503/adding-150-000-records-to-a-listview-without-freezing-ui/24422586#24422586 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24482731/vb2012-textbox-backcolor-doest-change-using-thread/24483443#24483443

Comment: Sorry man i've take a look just now but my first idea is to remove all the code filter data to extract only which are not accepted show it stop it if rowcount is different from previous read show message button.All this could be done in background worker with any issue and you can use simple datagridview to achieve your goal.Let me if i misunderstand the situation please.

Comment: @Adrian read the data=> clean the source=>bind data to control => finished

Comment: @MrCoDeXeR you're right but when a backgourworker is completed it can access to each control without lock the gui and without issue about any other suff also he can use threapool which is more faster too.

Comment: I'm still open for solutions. I will see which one works the best.

Comment: @makemoney2010, could you provide information pertaining that a threadpool is faster? Also when a background worker is completed, UI controls can be updated, his issue was trying to update the UI controls in the background worker not using a delegate to access those controls and update them :)

Comment: @makemoney2010 On another note, you'll want to use a BackgroundWorker if you have a single task that runs in the background and needs to interact with the UI. The task of marshalling data and method calls to the UI thread are handled automatically through its event-based model. As for a threadpool, using one should be used when efficiency is desired. The ThreadPool helps avoid the overhead associated with creating, starting, and stopping threads. You want to avoid using them if: the task runs the lifetime of the application or you need it to be a background thread.

Comment: @makemoney2010 Also, if you intend to interact with the UI afterwards, you should be aware that the operation is running in a non-UI thread when using a ThreadPool.

Comment: Here is my complete code for those that have suggestions. I am aware of the empty subs and timers which aren't used. This is in the mission of trying to get rid of the LAG : http://pastebin.com/BzhL2yej

Comment: @Adriaan I can't see it here from work, I would have to look at it later, sorry about that.

Comment: @MrCoDeXeR : No prob. I'm also still at work and going home in about 15 minutes

Comment: @MrCoDeXeR i'm sorry but i was out playing with my daugther.I saw all what you wrote and i agree with especially about the fact that threadpool is very usefull for efficiency pourpose.However it could be very usefull also to make some internal task without freeze gui.In example if i have 2-3-4-10-20 tasks to perfrom asyncronusly i prefer use thradpoll give to them a manual reset event( max 32 for 32 bit max 64 for 64 bit) and each of them make is work without i have to take care of any other stuff.This is personal vision.

Comment: Running thread in non UI thread could thrown in crossthreadexception which require a little bit of attention.But is not difficult to do.Personally i wrote an application which work with 112 DBs mysql/mssql of classified ads with different structer which update, delete,import and make many other stuff in background with background worker for long hard trhead and with simple threadpool use for other speed task. :) And It work really fine :).However it is only a developer choice based on his needs.

Comment: I saw Adrian code and personally i'm little bit oriented to custom class which expose several methods base per his needs that could be called async and sync in order to provide better performance.Also personalli avoid listitem i thought it could be better(but is my personal advice) a gridview which is more light to bind.That's may view point nothing else :)

Comment: we dont add SOLVED to titles here, we have checkmarks for that

Comment: @Plutonix : Sorry. I'm still new here. makemoney2010 : I also like gridview, but the owner of the company doesn't want it so.