# Filling DataGridView from BackgroundWorker

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2012, datagridview, backgroundworker

This is the case:
I have a `DataGridView` in form and when I start the form `DGV` should start filling with `BackgroundWorker`.

```
Private Sub FirstSub()
    adoconn()
    Me.Enabled = False
    bw.RunWorkerAsync()
    Me.Enabled = True
End Sub

Private Sub bw_DoWork(sender As Object, e As DoWorkEventArgs) Handles bw.DoWork

    Dim worker As BackgroundWorker = CType(sender, BackgroundWorker)
    If DataGridView1.InvokeRequired Then
        '//For VB 10 you can use an anonymous sub
        DataGridView1.Invoke(Sub() bw_DoWork(sender, e))
    Else


        Try
            DataBaseLayer.FillDTwithSP("ArticlesSelect", ds_Tables.Articles)
            Me.DataGridView1.DataSource = ds_Tables.Articles
            Me.DataGridView1.ClearSelection()

        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.ToString)
        End Try
    End If

End Sub
```

After Carlos giving me an example of what should I do, I did this, but now I have a problem that when I place BrakePoint is doesn't even get into `bw_DoWork` sub

```
Private Sub FirstSub()
    adoconn()
    Me.Enabled = False
    bw.WorkerReportsProgress = True
    AddHandler bw.DoWork, AddressOf bw_DoWork
    AddHandler bw.ProgressChanged, AddressOf bw_ProgressChanged
    Me.Enabled = True
End Sub
Private Sub bw_ProgressChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As ProgressChangedEventArgs)
    Try
        DataBaseLayer.FillDTwithSP("ArticlesSelect", ds_Tables.Articles)
            Me.DataGridView1.DataSource = ds_Tables.Articles
            Me.DataGridView1.ClearSelection()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    End Try
End Sub
Private Sub bw_DoWork(sender As Object, e As DoWorkEventArgs)
    Dim worker As BackgroundWorker = CType(sender, BackgroundWorker)
    bw.ReportProgress(sender, e)
End Sub
```

So, my desired thing is to disable all controls on form until my `DataTable` is filled and `DataGridView` is showing a result set from `DT`. 
The thing is that when I load this form it freeze and un-freeze again when everything is done, so there is no effect of `BackgroundWorker` at all.

If you need any more info or code parts feel free to tell me so I can solve this problem.

Thanks,
Hoh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reviewing some of the details of this thread I can point out a few things I see.

1. You are trying to set your source in `ProgressChanged Event`, no need if you have a delegate and use it properly.
2. The `Progress Changed Event` should only be used to report progress, not change UI or any controls.
3. No need to add handlers as they are already taken care of.

I am not sure where your calling `FirstSub` method, I would assume from a load event or click event perhaps, that doesn't matter anyways. Below are changes that I made and should be good for you. You can also check out my other answer's [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24482731/vb2012-textbox-backcolor-doest-change-using-thread/24483443#24483443) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24421503/adding-150-000-records-to-a-listview-without-freezing-ui/24422586#24422586), both are great for you to reference and see what need's to take place.

```
 Delegate Sub SetDataTable(ByVal dt As DataTable) 'Your delegate..

 Private Sub FirstSub()
    adoconn()
    Me.Enabled = False
    bw.RunWorkerAsync()
    Me.Enabled = True
 End Sub

 'The method that fills DataGridView1
 Private Sub AddSource(ByVal dt As DataTable)
    If Me.DataGridView1.InvokeRequired Then 'Invoke if required...
        Dim d As New SetDataTable(AddressOf AddSource) 
        Me.Invoke(d, New Object() {dt})
    Else 'Otherwise, no invoke required...
        Me.DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
        Me.DataGridView1.ClearSelection()
    End If
 End Sub

 Private Sub bw_DoWork(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles bw.DoWork
    If Not (bw.CancellationPending) Then
        DataBaseLayer.FillDTwithSP("ArticlesSelect", ds_Tables.Articles)
        AddSource(ds_Tables.Articles)
    ElseIf (bw.CancellationPending) Then
        e.Cancel = True
    End If
 End Sub
```

Let me know how this works out for you and check the other two links I gave you. Also on another note you could change the call in the `DoWork` to your method AddSource to not pass the `DataTable` and just call it...

MrCodexer

Comment: Hello MrCodexer, infortunatelly I am receive this message after doing exactly what you said.  http://imgur.com/XQweeyu

Comment: Is this project to big to zip up so I can take a look at it?

Comment: Also, you code: DataBaseLayer.FillDTwithSP("ArticlesSelect", ds_Tables.Articles) is probably where you may be getting your error at, did you set a breakpoint on it?

Comment: If your error is there move that code out and put into the AddSource... I explained this in my post...

Comment: um, something else was a problem (renaming DGV headers). BUT, seems like that form is showing, than BW starts working and than form is frozen until DGV is filled (it's not even disabled), it's all enabled (but not available to write in (textboxes).)

Comment: I can say why your form is frozen is because in your method FirstSub, you say: Me.Enabled = False and then re-enable it after the DoWork event... That's exactly why, I seen that but left that as that's what you had.

Comment: Nope, that's not a case. Feel free to add me on Skype (Hohstapler90) if you have some free time to help me out with this.

Comment: At work, I possibly could later when home. Im testing something right now involving this same issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58007/discussion-between-hoh-and-mr-codexer).  This is automated message by stackoverflow.

Comment: I can't do chat at work, but I can confirm that the code provided to you works perfectly. I create a table and such for my example and used exact same code provided to you and works perfectly. There is something else in your code that I can't see that is causing your issues.

Comment: There is actually nothing else in my code, except Form.Load where I call FirstSub sub. So, the thing is that when I start Form it gets frozen untill DGV is filled, after that I can work on form normaly.
Even if I remove. Me.Enabled=False the same is happening, so form is not getting disabled, just frozen.
Anyway, what I want to get out of this is disabling all controls in form untill DGV is filled and in the mean time (in time that is DGV getting filled) I want to show a .gif Loading image, to make it smooth for those who will watch the form, since DGV is getting filled with more than 50k rows

Comment: If you look at my links provided you will see these :)

Comment: Isn't that like I need a loop for that in this case? Since I have no loop where should I put Threading.Thread.Sleep(100) ?

Comment: Anyway, even if I had that idea to make this look nice and smooth, I think I will just change my approach (since I possibly will be not able to make it), so I will just make it in old fashioned way with SearchTextBox so there will be a lot less records in datatable.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the Event ProgressChanged, that executes the code in the UI thread, so you can safely update your controls:

```
_backgroundWorker.ProgressChanged += New ProgressChangedEventHandler(backgroundWorker_ProgressChanged)
```

Inside the Do_Work, invoke the progress like that:

```
 //param is the value you need to update your controls
  _backgroundWorker.ReportProgress(p, param)

  Private Sub backgroundWorker_ProgressChanged(sender As Object, e As    ProgressChangedEventArgs)

       ' Update the UI here         
  End Sub
```

No need to use InvokeRequired insode the ProgressChanged event.

Comment: Can you please provide me a code in VB.net? I am not that much familiar with C#. Thanks.

Comment: I added my new code into question, now I have a new problem, so can't even say does this work or not.

Comment: "After Carlos giving me an example of what should I do, I did this, but now I have a problem that when I place BrakePoint is doesn't even get into bw_DoWork sub"